# console.table return undefined and can't show value returned from a function?

Tags: web3js, javascript, external-api

Hello everybody hope all is good ?

I need help please,
I have 2 functions : ***1st*** **return a value** after fetching and url(api) and ***2nd*** it **log in table** value returned but it didn't work :(

This is my code :

```
function One () { fetch(url).then(function (a) {return a.json()}).then(function(b){

    const b = a.data
    const c = something;
    return b;  >>>>> This return example '56'(if i do console.log).
}
```

***I want log this return in function Two so i do :***

```
function Two() { 
        console.table(One())
}
```

> > > 
> >
> > and ***it return undefined*** but it need to return '56' :(
> >
> > > 

What is the problem please ? Sincerely Mike